# processing a list of files in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I am new to SLURM. I would like to process a long list of files in parallel. Specifically, I have a script to process a single like

```
./process.sh filename
```

Now I want to process many files in a file list like

```
file1
file2
file3
...
file10000
```

How do I process the file list in parallel (that is, using 16 CPUs) using SLURM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `--array` option. For example, if your compute nodes are shared, the following job script should be close to what you want to do.

```
#SBATCH -J JOBNAME
#SBATCH -o JOBNAME.%J.stdout
#SBATCH -e JOBNAME.%J.stderr
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --array 1-10000

./process.sh file${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
```

Comment: Thanks, it saves my day!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer resolved the problem, please consider accepting it as a solution:) Thanks!